# Why is $2{\vec d\cdot \vec m\over \vec m\cdot \vec m}\vec m-\vec d=(0,1)$?

Tags: geometry, vectors

How do we calculate
$$2{\vec d\cdot \vec m\over \vec m\cdot \vec m}\vec m-\vec d$$

given the data ${\vec d = (1, 0)}$ and ${\vec m = (1, 1)}$?

The answer should be $(0, 1)$, but I don't know why.

Comment: Show your work.

Comment: Just apply the definition of the dot product, and the fraction simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}\,$.

Comment: Note in case this is what is confusing you: the dot products take vectors as inputs, but give scalars as outputs. There are no components of a dot product.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $2\cdot \frac{\binom{1}{0} \cdot \binom{1}{1}}{\binom{1}{1} \cdot \binom{1}{1}}\binom{1}{1} - \binom{1}{0}$ = $ 2\cdot \frac{1\cdot 1+0\cdot 1}{1\cdot 1+1\cdot 1} \binom{1}{1} - \binom{1}{0}$ = $\binom{1}{1} - \binom{1}{0} = \binom {0}{1}$

Comment: Basically I'm looking formula for x and y

Comment: I don't understand, do you mean you want the definition of the dot product?

Comment: The ended result is (0, 1) how can I calculate only x or only y from this?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by $x$ and $y$, but if you're referring to $x$ as the horizontal component of the vector, and $y$ as the vertical, then traditionally, $x$ = the 'top' component and $y$ = the 'bottom' component

Comment: I mean first and second coordinate

Comment: @Nadfrw So your first coordinate is $0$ and your second coordinate is $1$?

Answer (score 1):

$$2{\vec d\cdot \vec m\over \vec m\cdot \vec m}\vec m-\vec d=2\cdot\frac{1}{2}\vec m-\vec d
=\vec m-\vec d=(0,1)$$

Comment: @Nadfrw do you see any answer you can accept?